# Investigate the differentiability of $f(x) = x + \sqrt{|x^2 -1|}$

Tags: calculus

I have tried but have doubts if 
 $f(x) = x + \sqrt{|x^2 -1|}$ is differentiable for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ I need some help.

Comment: Which points could be a problem for differentiability?

Comment: What does it mean for a function to be differentiable at a point?  Think back to a particular definition.

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x)=x+\sqrt{x^2-1}, x \ge 1; f(x)=x+\sqrt{1-x^2}, x<1.$$
The right derivative for $x\ge 1$ is
$$f'(x)=1+\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}m f'(1)=\infty$$
Similarly the left derivative for $x<1$ is
$$f'(x)=1-\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}, f'(1)=-\infty$$
So the $f(x)$ is non differentiable at $x=1$, there is a common vertical tangent that forms a cusp at $x=1$.